# Missing option tabs in Catalyst Control Center

Tags: windows-8, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

My Specs:

- CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 CPU 1055T (6x2.8Ghz)
- RAM: 12GB (mixed
  manufacturer - had the problem before I upgraded so it should be
  irrelevant)
- GPU: Sapphire Radeon HD5830
- OS: Windows 8 (newest updates installed)

[image]

As you can see there are a lot missing tabs and options. I completely uninstalled my driver plus cleaned the registry and reinstalled the newest driver - the result was the same. I can also notice an performance problem - playing Battlefield 3 on lowest options still just gives me 30-50FPS even though it should have around 100 FPS (judging from videos etc..) Not just Battlefield, but as well as other games like Saints Row and GTA IV they are unplayabe on higher settings even though they should be.

I even tried the newest beta driver but with the same result.

Comment: Upgrading to Windows 8.1 and the latest (as of when this comment was written) Windows 8 beta driver from AMD fixed this for me. I guess support got a little dodgy until Microsoft released Windows 8.1 and AMD released drivers for the R series graphics cards?

Comment: Wow! I posted a question with the same content as this one except it was Windows 7 and I was showing the exact tab I was missing and with a screenshot of how it was and how it is now.
Got 4 downvotes in less than 15 minutes! Not a single comment saying it was duplicated or why the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that the Catalyst Control Center is being upgraded, the problem is that the AMD Vision Engine Control Center is being installed.

To get back the options once you've upgraded, uninstall/downgrade to version 11.11. This will give you an AMD Vision Control Center, replacing the old Catalyst Control Center  It still has the advanced options that were missing.

Next, install the latest driver by doing a Custom install and deselecting the AMD Vision Control Engine. That will preserve the keep those options while still upgrading everything else.